# Bash one liner for calculating the average of a specific row of numbers in bash

Tags: awk, average, mean, one-liner

I just began learning bash.

Trying to figure out how to convert a two-liner into a one liner using bash.

The First Line of code...

1. searches the first column of the input.txt for the word - KEYWORD.
2. captures every number in this KEYWORD row from column2 until the last column.
3. dumps all these numbers into the values.txt file placing each number on a new line.

The second line of code calculates average value  for all the numbers in the first column of values txt the prints out the this value.

```
awk '{if($1=="KEYWORD") for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' input.txt > values.txt
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0; counter=0}{sum+=$1; counter+=1}END{print sum/counter}' values.txt
```

How do I create a one liner from this?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Your scripts are awk, not bash. They'd do the same thing in any shell. Awk and bash are 2 completely different tools.

Comment: Ed - I named this Bash one liner because of http://www.bashoneliners.com & https://onceupon.github.io/Bash-Oneliner. It appears this can be called many things.

Comment: Will figure out how to add sample input & sample results to future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN { count = sum = 0 }
  $1 == "KEYWORD" {
    for (n = 2; n <= NF; n++) sum += $n
    count += NF - 1
  }
  END { print sum/count }' input.txt
```

Just keep track of the sum and total count of numbers in the first (and only) pass through the file and then average them at the end instead of printing a value for each matching line.

Comment: Thx, Shawn!   When I modified your solution to make count = -1, it gave me the right answer!  Got tips on how to sharpen my one-liner skills?

Comment: @LockhartTech That's weird that you needed -1.

Comment: I think that's because the values to be averaged began from the third column not the 2nd column as I mistakenly indicated.

Comment: @LockhartTech Yeah, that would throw things off if you didn't adjust the line that increments `count` appropriately along with the column to start summing from.

Comment: You don't need the BEGIN section and you might want to make the END section `print (count ? sum/count : 0)` or similar so you don't get a divide by zero error when no lines contain KEYWORD.

Comment: Ed thx for the tips - didn't know about all these techniques. As usual, seems like there many ways to get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this problem with several people and learning some new bash/awk shortcuts, the code below appears to be the shortest answer.

`awk '/KEYWORD/{for(n=3;n<=NF;n++)sum+=$n;print sum/(NF-2)}' input.txt`

This code searches the input file for the row containing "KEYWORD".

Then sums up all the field from the 3rd column to the last column.

Then prints out the average value of all those numbers. (i.e. the mean).